# How to copy a column if the criteria is met within the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, conditional-statements, criteria

I am trying to copy column B into column E based off of a criteria in C. However, I can't seem to figure out how to copy the data into the matching row .

For example , I would like it be executed like this { matching with the corresponding text in column B to E if column (C=x)}

Column > A | B | C | D | E

---

```
         A   X       A
         B   Y
         C   X       C
```

---

Here's what I have

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim textSG As String
Dim erow As Long

x = 3 
erow = 0

Do while Worksheet.Cell(x, 3) <> ""    
    If InStr ((Worksheet.Cells(x, 3)),"X" > 0 Then    
        textSG = Worksheet.Cells(x, 2)    
        erow = erow + 3    
        Worksheet.Cells(erow, 5) = textSG
    End if 
    x = x + 1 
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. I think it does what you intend.

```
Dim R       As Long

For R = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    ' case insensitive comparison
    If StrComp(Trim(Cells(R, 3).Value), "x", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Cells(R, 5).Value = Cells(R, 2).Value
    End If
Next R
```